# Auto Registering Factory Stops Working In Source Files

Tags: c++, c++17

I am trying to create a single process application that has a factory for a bunch of classes. I thought I was being slick by making these classes auto register with a static factory.

I have an auto registering factory of derived classes:

```
template <typename T>
class Register {
public:
    Register();
private:
    static bool register_type();
    inline static const bool registered_ = register_type();
};

template <typename T>
Register<T>::Register() {
    (void)registered_;
}

template <typename T>
bool Register<T>::register_type() {
    constexpr auto name = typenameAsCstr<T>();
    NodeFactory::registerNode<NodeType>(name);
    return true;
}
```

This registers derived types into a static factory:

header

```
class Factory {
public:
    Factory();
    template<typename T> static void register(std::string const & name);

private:
    using CreateFunction = std::function<std::unique_ptr<Derived>(std::string const)>;
    using FactoryType = std::unordered_map<std::string, CreateFunction>;
    static FactoryType & factoryMap();
    static void register(std::string const & kind, CreateFunction creation);
};
```

source

```
auto Factory::factoryMap() -> FactoryType & {
    static FactoryType factory{};
    return factory;
}

void Factory::register(std::string const & kind, CreateFunction creation) {
    factoryMap().emplace(kind, creation);
}
```

this has been working with header only derived classes:

```
class Derived : Register<Derived> {
public:
    Derived(...) {}
};
```

When the derived class is header only it works great, but when I try to use a source file for the constructor's definition it is no longer registering the derived class. I have no idea why this is the case.

I tried moving the derived definition into a source file

```
class Derived : Register<Derived> {
public:
    Derived(...);
};
```

source

```
Derived::Derived(...) {}
```

Comment: What is your question?  It seems to be similar to [your earlier question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75328967/how-to-use-a-static-member-factory-with-multiple-static-libaries), which also doesn't include a question.  This code also has [many errors](https://godbolt.org/z/edYPTv3o1), which you don't mention.

Comment: @DrewDormann Idk, but I think it is not that ambiguous. You just add "Why" to *"When the derived class is header only it works great, but when I try to use a source file for the constructor's definition it is no longer registering the derived class."*
Though a reproducible example would be nice to have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The earlier question talks about static libraries. That's important.

If you have a source file in a library, the linker will pull it in *only* if something else refers to the symbols in that file. Otherwise it will be skipped.

Except for this "auto registration" thing, this is exctly what you want - we don't want the entire standard library linked into every program. You instead want things like `sin` and `cos` linked *only* if you actually call these functions, not because some of the files *could* also contain some registration code.

Comment: Thank you so much. This was it. I was able to fix it with:
target_link_libraries(${APP_NAME} -Wl,--whole-archive ${derived_lib}-Wl,--no-whole-archive)